# Rscript launch custom R

Tags: r, rscript, debian-based

**Do you know how to specify R binary which will be launched by `Rscript`?**

It points to `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` by default.

```
$ Rscript --verbose -e 'Sys.getenv("R_HOME")'

running
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore -e Sys.getenv("R_HOME")'

[1] "/usr/lib/R"
```

I have configured alternatives for `/usr/bin/R`, and can switch between R.

For `R`:

```
$ update-alternatives --display R
R - auto mode
  link currently points to /opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/R
/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/R - priority 200
/usr/lib/R/bin/R - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/R'.
```

For `Rscript`:

```
$ update-alternatives --display Rscript
Rscript - auto mode
  link currently points to /opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript
/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript - priority 200
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript - priority 100
Current 'best' version is '/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript'.
```

I cannot find the way, how to force `Rscript` launch `/usr/bin/R` instead of `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`.

---

## Update

@dirk-eddelbuettel has suggested to use environment `PATH`. **Despite the set of `PATH`, `Rscript` still uses `/usr/lib/R/bin/R`**

```
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin:/opt/python/conda/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Launching Rscript

```
$ Rscript --version && Rscript --verbose -e 'print("Hello")'
    R scripting front-end version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
    running
      '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore -e print("Hello")'

    [1] "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need different `Rscript` variants from two builds. I just do it via `$PATH`:

```
edd@max:~$ Rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
edd@max:~$ Rscript-devel.sh --version
R scripting front-end version 3.3.0 Under development (unstable) (2016-02-07 r70118)
edd@max:~$
```

I could have called this anything. I chose to end it in `.sh` as it is a shell wrapper:

```
edd@max:~$ cat ~/bin/Rscript-devel.sh 
#!/bin/bash

export R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/lib/R-devel/lib/R/library:/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library::/usr/lib/R/library'}
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/R-devel/bin:$PATH"
Rscript "$@"
edd@max:~$
```

*Edit:*  As requested though I fail to understand why you cannot do that yourself:

```
edd@max:~$ Rscript --verbose -e '2+2'
running
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore -e 2+2'

[1] 4
edd@max:~$ Rscript-devel.sh --verbose -e '2+2'
running
  '/usr/local/lib/R-devel/lib/R/bin/R --slave --no-restore -e 2+2'

[1] 4
edd@max:~$
```

Comment: Can you please show output of `$ Rscript-devel.sh --version --verbose -e 'print("Dirk is awesome!")'`?

Comment: Would you mind please to show output of the `--verbose` for `Rscript-devel.sh`?

Comment: What you showed first behaves the same way as `Rscript --verbose` does.  Both fail. It's built-in.  Normal behaviour works. You try this yourself _which is why I showed you the whole script_.

Comment: Hmm...I had done what you have suggested from the beggining, but in my case, despite set of `PATH` `Rscript-devel.sh` still calls `/usr/lib/R/bin/R` :( I will keep digging.

Comment: The PATH setting needs to correspond to where YOUR version of R-devel is installed.

Comment: sure :) i am not simply copying your script, i have adjusted the location. In my case it is in `/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/bin` and `/opt/R/3.2.3/usr/lib/R/library`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103104/discussion-between-cronacronis-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: No, I don't have time for one on one tutoring. Feel free to post on the r-sig-debian list (or even on r-help).  You have a simple deployment problem of your R-devel build.